# Import a Listener Component into JIRA CLOUD

Tags: plugins, cloud, jira

I have developed a Listener Plugin which triggers mail to external Users Populated in Custom Field value. This plugin is developed in JIRA server which has atlassian-plugin.xml.

I am trying to transform this atlassian-plugin.xml to atlassian-conect.json file to upload the same plugin in JIRA Cloud , but unable to move ahead with Component Imports and Web resources.

my **attlassian-plugin.xml**

```
<component-import key="eventPublisher" interface="com.atlassian.event.api.EventPublisher"/>
    <component key="eventListener" class="com.example.tutorial.plugins.IssueCreatedResolvedListener">
        <description>Class that processes the incoming JIRA issue events.</description>
    </component>
```

**IssueCreatedResolvedListener.java**

```
    @EventListener
        public void onIssueEvent(IssueEvent issueEvent) throws GenericEntityException {
        Long eventTypeId = issueEvent.getEventTypeId();
        Issue issue = issueEvent.getIssue();
        CustomField customField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Customer Email Address");
        Object customFieldValue = customField.getValue(issue);

if (customFieldValue != null && eventTypeId.equals(EventType.ISSUE_CREATED_ID)) {
    mail.sendEmail(customFieldValue.toString()," test mail from jira"," test mail from jira","text");

}
```

Please help me with the steps involved in uploading my custom plugin to jira cloud .

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples, ie what have you tried, and what errors did you get?

Comment: I have updated the post with the code sample. thanks